# phpmyadmin as default site on dedicated server

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin

We build a Ubuntu 18.04 server dedicated for running phpMyAdmin.
Databases are on several different servers and are accessed remotely.
No other services or sites are running on this server.
We want the phpMyAdmin site to be the default site.
At the moment the server is showing a Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page.

Basicaly we would like that `http://server/` is showing the same site as `http://server/phpmyadmin`.

We tried to setup a redirect which seems to get stuck in an infinite loop:

```
redirect permanent / /phpmyadmin
```

or

```
redirect permanent / http://server/phpmyadmin
```

The result is that there are numerous appends of the string phpmyadmin to the original url until the browser cuts the redirects off.

Comment: simply as changing the root directory to the webserver config file adding /phpmyadmin. in your apache conf file look for the document root directive and modify accordingly. Then restart apache service.

Comment: or either, move the phpmyadmin content all one level up to the root directory. There is definetively no need for redirections

Comment: @LelioFaieta phpmyadmin isn't in the www folder

Comment: it is in a subfolder for what i see from the url. You can make that the www root or move it to the www root. On apache2 the www root or document root is a parameter you can setup

Comment: @LelioFaieta the URL `/phpmyadmin` is aliased from a folder outside of the www one.

Comment: @Cid no, definitively not true on ubuntu systems like OP is saying is the server he uses

Comment: The actual phpmyadmin installation on a Ubuntu 18.04 is located in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/ while the apache document root is set to /var/www/html

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file `/etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf` or `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`

Line 1 should looks like this : `Alias /phpmyadmin "some/path"`

Change it to :

```
Alias / "some/path"
```

And restart apache

Comment: there is not a conf-available for phpmyadmin in apache2 on ubuntu if you manually installed phpmyadmin

Comment: there is not either a /etc/phpyadmin folder on ubuntu systems if you manually install phpmyadmin. phpmyadmin is just a folder in your www root or anywhere else accessible by www_data user

Comment: I already did try this myself and it unfortunatly triggerd the same loop as the standard redirects did.

Comment: @snhel5 did you remove the redirection you wrote ?

Comment: Yes. Redirects were removed.

Answer (score 0):

in your apache2.conf find this:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and update `/var/www/` to `/var/www/phpmyadmin`

or move phpmyadmin content to /var/www as you prefer

Comment: This is generating a 403. The /var/log/apache2/error.log shows:`[authz_core:error] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/`

Comment: Depending on the apache version you are running you can fix it different ways. See [the manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/ClientDeniedByServerConfiguration)

Comment: I sort of fixed it. your suggestion to move the phpmyadmin content helped to come up with a solution.

Comment: I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

In the answers given it was suggested to move the phpmyadmin installation one level up.
This was not possible in my case due to the installation being in a different path.
This however pointed me in a different possible direction to a solution.

Here is how we eventually made it work like we wanted to.
Just 2 simple steps in the end.

1. Remove the folder which is used by Apache as default. In my case this was the /var/www/html. I found this location in the file /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf. look for the value of DocumentRoot.
2. Create a symbolic link instead of the removed folder. The redirect is now taking place on the file system level before Apache accesses them. In my case this link looks like this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   22 Jun 17 12:31 html -> /usr/share/phpmyadmin/
```